# android sms sending to received number

Tags: android, sms

My goal is to create a sms server that is capable of sending sms to users who requested by sending sms... I created first broadcast receiver to receive sms and get sender num and message body..
with that body (roll no) another activity with that roll no results in marks of that person..
at first i passed message body from broadcastreceiver to activity..
Here's is my BroadcastReceiver code :

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(arg1.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        String msgBody;
        if(bundle!=null) {
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    Toast.makeText(arg0, "SenderNum :" + msg_from + "msg :" + msgBody,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN");
                    in.putExtra("get_msg", msgBody);
                    arg0.sendBroadcast(in);
                }
                msg_from = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                String msg = arg1.getStringExtra("string");
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "Sms sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(msg_from, null, msg, null, null);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }`
```

and after that message body will get compared with existing database of roll no's if found pass this string of marks to broadcastreceiver for sending SMS to user...
Here's my Activity code :

```
public class MyApp extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    EditText editRollno,editName,editMarks;
    Button btnAdd,btnDelete,btnModify,btnView,btnViewAll,btnShowInfo;
SQLiteDatabase db;

String s;
String s1,s2,s3;
String str,str1;
private BroadcastReceiver bd;
IncomingSms is = new IncomingSms();
String pNumber;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    registerReceiver(is,new IntentFilter("MyReceiver"));
    Intent i = new Intent("MyReceiver");
    i.putExtra("string", s3);
    sendBroadcast(i);
    editRollno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editRollno);
    editName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editMarks=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editMarks);
    btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnDelete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnModify=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnModify);
    btnView=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    btnViewAll=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewAll);
    btnShowInfo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowInfo);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnModify.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnView.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnShowInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(rollno VARCHAR,name VARCHAR,marks VARCHAR);");



}
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(view==btnAdd)
    {
        if(editRollno.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
           editName.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
           editMarks.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            showMessage("Error", "Please enter all values");
            return;
        }
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('"+editRollno.getText()+"','"+editName.getText()+
                   "','"+editMarks.getText()+"');");
        showMessage("Success", "Record added");
        clearText();
    }
    if(view==btnDelete)
    {
        if(editRollno.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            showMessage("Error", "Please enter Rollno");
            return;
        }
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='"+editRollno.getText()+"'",     null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM student WHERE rollno='"+editRollno.getText()+"'");
            showMessage("Success", "Record Deleted");
        }
        else
        {
            showMessage("Error", "Invalid Rollno");
        }
        clearText();
    }
    if(view==btnModify)
    {
        if(editRollno.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            showMessage("Error", "Please enter Rollno");
            return;
        }
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='"+editRollno.getText()+"'", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            db.execSQL("UPDATE student SET name='"+editName.getText()+"',marks='"+editMarks.getText()+
                    "' WHERE rollno='"+editRollno.getText()+"'");
            showMessage("Success", "Record Modified");
        }
        else
        {
            showMessage("Error", "Invalid Rollno");
        }
        clearText();
    }
    if(view==btnView)
    {

            if(editRollno.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Please enter Rollno");
                return;
            }
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='"+editRollno.getText()+"'", null);
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                editName.setText(c.getString(1));
                editMarks.setText(c.getString(2));

            }
            else
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Invalid Rollno");
                clearText();
            }
        }


    if(view==btnViewAll)
    {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
        if(c.getCount()==0)
        {
            showMessage("Error", "No records found");
            return;
        }
        StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            buffer.append("Rollno: "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Name: "+c.getString(1)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Marks: "+c.getString(2)+"\n\n");
        }
        showMessage("Student Details", buffer.toString());
    }
    if(view==btnShowInfo)
    {
        showMessage("Student Management Application", "Developed By Azim");
    }
}



public void showMessage(String title,String message)
{
    Builder builder=new Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
public void clearText()
{
    editRollno.setText("");
    editName.setText("");
    editMarks.setText("");
    editRollno.requestFocus();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter ifl = new IntentFilter("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN");
    bd = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String msg = arg1.getStringExtra("get_msg");


            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='"+ msg +"'", null);
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                s1 = c.getString(1);
                s2 = c.getString(2);
                s3 = s1.concat(s2);


            }
            else
            {

            }

        }

    };
    this.registerReceiver(bd, ifl);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.bd);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    unregisterReceiver(is);
    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```

After executing this,it receives the sms but not sending sms bt it toasts sms sent...i can't able to understand ..plzzz help me..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
msg_from = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();
String msg = arg1.getStringExtra("string");
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0); // <-- add this
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(msg_from, null, msg, sentPI, null); //<-- Add this
Toast.makeText(arg0, "Sms sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //<-- move it here
```